# Retrieve Javascript File with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two websites hosted on the same server: www.examplea.com and www.exampleb.com

Example A is the primary site, and holds lots of files that Example B uses, however their root directories are parallel.

Example A = public_html/examplea

Example B = public_html/exampleb

Whenever Example B wants to use an image file, I retrieve it from Example A using an htaccess redirect and PHP script:

**htaccess:**

```
RewriteRule images/(.*)\.(jpg)$ /site_images/getimage.php?&image=$1 [NC,L]
```

**PHP:**

```
$image = $_GET["image"];
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('../examplea/images/'.$image.'.jpg');
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

This all works perfectly (I've stripped out all validation, this is just an example), however I'd like to do the same type of process for Javascript files, is there a way to do this?

I've tried using `readfile` but this just dumps the output, whereas I would much prefer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.exampleb.com/javascript/file.js"></script>
```

to be displayed in the browser, even though it will actually be calling the file from examplea.com

Is this possible?  I'm struggling to find the correct terminology for a useful Google search.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like it could be solved with a proper rewriterule, or aliasing the js file, or copying the js file. Since js files aren't uploaded by users why not just copy or alias them?

Comment: The `rewriterule` appears to want to effect only `images/` the PHP appears to also be for `images/`, so why is it that `javascript/` is effected by this rule? If you move the `.htaccess` file to `images/` does that solve the problem?

Comment: @OIS The issue is that these Javascript files contain jquery that points to local php functions files, so when I just do them simply with the htaccess rule it attempts to use the php files that are on examplea.com and of course jquery does not work cross domain.
When you suggest copying the file, do you mean via an automated process or just actually copying the files?  I'd like to be able to change the files on examplea.com and not have to bother modifying exampleb.com

Comment: @doveyg It does only affect images in the example, I just showed it to identify what I'm already doing for images - they are actually also being watermarked which is why I have a php function for it, but it's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: @JoeP You said you wanted to load it from exampleb not examplea. You can also use git submodules or npm repo. So many possibilities ...

Comment: If its not really relevant it doesn't need to be there. There is no standard reason why linking the Javascript file as you have done shouldn't work. You should post your `httpd.conf` file so we can find the issue.